# How to use Linq with Castle ActiveRecord

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm, castle-activerecord

I am playing around with Castle ActiveRecord and noticed that the download included the file, `Castle.ActiveRecord.Linq.dll`. I haven't found any documentation for using Linq with ActiveRecord, only [some](http://whereslou.com/2008/04/10/linq-for-activerecord) [old](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/02/16/Linq-for-NHibernate-Adventures.aspx) [blog posts](http://www.kenegozi.com/Blog/2007/11/18/activerecord-dot-linq-naive-but-working.aspx).

What is the usage pattern? Is `Castle.ActiveRecord.Linq` ready for production use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, Castle.ActiveRecord.Linq is production ready. It's included in the latest ActiveRecord release. The actual Linq provider is implemented in NHibernate.Linq.dll, the ActiveRecord Linq dll is a thin pass-through layer. There are basically two ways to use it:

1. Make your entities inherit from `ActiveRecordLinqBase<T>`, then to query:

   ```
   var blogs = (from b in Blog.Queryable select b).ToList();
   ```
2. Use `ActiveRecordLinq.AsQueryable<T>`, e.g.:

   ```
   var blogs = (from b in ActiveRecordLinq.AsQueryable<Blog>() select b).ToList();
   ```

Look at the [tests](http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.ActiveRecord/tree/master/src/Castle.ActiveRecord.Linq.Tests/) for some sample code.

**UPDATE**: as of ActiveRecord 3.0 beta, Linq is integrated into Castle.ActiveRecord.dll, and NHibernate.Linq.dll is no more (integrated into NHibernate.dll as of NHibernate 3)

Comment: I edited your answer so I could upvote it. It wouldn't let me upvote until an edit, for some reason.