# Within ActiveRecordMediator, should use Execute or CreateSession?

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord, isession

Suppose I'm going to do something that needs access to NHibernate's `ISession`. For example running a Sql query via `ISQLQuery` or running a LINQ-to-NHibernate via `session.Linq<MyType>()`. I know there is 2 way to access `ISession`:

1. `ActiveRecordMediator.GetSessionFactoryHolder().CreateSession()`
2. `ActiveRecordMediator.Execute()`

What is the pros and cons of each one? additionally is there another alternative ways?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any *technical* reason to prefer one over the other, however ActiveRecordMediator.Execute is the [documented way](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/usersguide/nativesql.html).

BTW you don't need any of this to do LINQ queries, you can use Castle.ActiveRecord.Linq instead.

Comment: It's seems that `ActiveRecord.Execute` handles session automatically but the other way does not. It may be is the cause of prefering `ActiveRecord.Execute` to other way in documentation. BTW is there any sample/documentation about `Castle.ActiveRecord.Linq`?

Comment: @afsharm: of course, getting the session yourself implies wrapping it in a `using` block. Re LINQ: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967777/how-to-use-linq-with-castle-activerecord